# Custom binder works fine, but the model is not updated

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have a model and it looks like this:

```
public class MyModel {
   public List<SomeBaseClass> list {get; set;}
   public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

where `SomeBaseClass` is in fact a base class and the list can contain items of different types, but all those types are inherited from `SomeBaseClass`.

To make sure my model binds properly, I had to implement a custom binder that fills out the model based on the form data.

```
public class MyModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
   public override object BindModel(ControllerContext cntxt, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
        var model = new MyModel {
            list = new List<SomeBaseClass>(),
            SomeProperty = ...
        };

        ... // some data mangling and type twisting here

        return model; // here the debugger shows that the model's list is populated properly based on the form data.
    }
}
```

But when a view calls an action, my model is not complete:

```
public string SomeAction(MyModel model) { // <~~ It calls the custom binder before coming to here, which is correct
   // As the result, the model variable is an instance of MyModel, but the list is null
   return "somethhing";
}
```

In the action method, I receive the model object with its `list` property set to **null**.  Which is strange, because the binder is called correctly and it populates the model and all its properties properly.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

**P.S.** When I try to call `UpdateModel<MyModel>(model);` in the action method, it throws "The model of type MyModel could not be updated."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I had to add the binder attribute next to my model class declaration to make sure the binder is called when the model is passed to the action method.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]
public class MyModel
{
...
}
```

It is not obvious, because even when this attribute is not present, the custom binder is still called, but for some reason its output is not being sent to the action, the default binder's output is used instead.